# How do you get a shortcut for Export>WaveFront to work?

Tags: export

I made a shortcut by right clicking the export wavefront menu item. Tried "W" but it didn't work. Tried "cntrl W" and got a save message.How do I make an Export to WaveFront shortcut? Couldn't find anything is user prefs.

Comment: Why did you try Ctrl+W? It's already binded by default to Save file action. Choose another binding, it should work

Comment: My mistake, I used Cmnd+W. I assumed Blender would let me know if there was a conflict and didn't realise custom shortcut keys were based on trial and error. Thank you.

Comment: You can switch search in the User prefs > Input to Key Binding (dropdown next to the search field) and search by key bindings. It won't be trial and error.

Comment: Thank you. I did search in user prefs for Export WaveFront shortcuts but didn't know about the other search option. Thanks. All is now working well.